# What does 'winning validator' mean in Sawtooth Network?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

Need help understanding the below statements quoted from [this](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/architecture/injecting_batches_block_validation_rules.html) documentation:

> **local** : A transaction must be signed by the same key as the block. This rule takes a list of transaction indices in the block and enforces the rule on each. This rule is useful in combination with the other rules to ensure a client is not submitting transactions that should only be injected by the `winning validator`.

**Question:**

What does `winning validator` mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "winning" validator is the one that gets to publish the next block on the blockchain. The losing validators do not get to publish the next block on the blockchain and instead accepts the published block from the winning validator.